# how do I use setInterval to add a classname at different times instead of adding it at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so what I am trying to create is a content slideshow. I have five html elements that are `absolute` positioned. The idea is to have elements hidden except the first one, then using `setInterval` i would like to add the hide class to to the all the elements except the one in current view.

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card first">first</div>
    <div class="card second ">second</div>
    <div class="card third ">third</div>
    <div class="card fourth ">fourth</div>
    <div class="card fifth ">fifth</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/* card will contain the general properties of the card element */
.card{
   position: absolute;
   width: 60%;
   height: 70%;
   
}
/* below will contain the individual properties of a card element */
.first{
    background-color: red;
}
.second{
    background-color: rgb(68, 97, 177);
}
.third{
    background-color: rgb(27, 221, 20);
}
.fourth{
    background-color: rgb(187, 0, 109);
}
.fifth{
    background-color: rgb(184, 204, 0);
    
    
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

and the javascript that i have

```
const containerElement = document.querySelectorAll('.card')




setInterval(() => {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < containerElement.length; i++) {
      
        containerElement[i].classList.add('hide')

    }
    
}, 5000);
```

The javascript I have noticed adds the class `hide` at the same time instead of gradually after 5 seconds each. Thanks.

Comment: You do realise that when you figure it out, the "fifth" card will obscure the other 4 anyway, so you won't see a change since you can't see the first 4 cards anyway? Not sure why you'd expect your code to do anything other than hide all the cards every 5 seconds anyway

Comment: I wanted the code to hide a single card every 5 seconds

Comment: sure, but one, two, three and four are hidden by five anyway :p

Comment: _" instead of gradually after 5 seconds each"_ - you have not _implemented_ "gradually" here. setInterval executes the function you have passed it every five second - but the function loops over _all_ elements, each and every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with a function called using `setTimeout`

```
const containerElement = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
function fn(i) {
  containerElement[i].classList.add('hide')
  if (i < containerElement.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(fn, 5000, i + 1);
  }
}
setTimeout(fn, 5000, 0);
```

Comment: you were right, the fifth element obscures everything. I had to add the hide class to every element then use classlist.remove to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: instead of `add` and `remove` you could use `toggle` to apply or remove the class on a condition